Compare 3 Case Statements to Output Pass or Fail
I currently have a dataset where different combinations of 3 columns would either result in a new column called “Overall Value” as PASS or FAIL.
For the 3 columns, I first need to standardize the different values in them to a PASS or FAIL. For example, if the column contained “good” or “passing score”, the value should be pass.  if it was “bad” or “unacceptable” or NULL than the value should be fail.  This same logic would then apply to the other 2 columns.
From there, for each row, if any of the 3 columns has a has a value of PASS the  the “Overall Value” is PASS, otherwise if all are “FAIL” then the “Overall Value” is FAIL
I created 3 separate case statements in my select statement to “Standardize” the values as PASS or FAIL and put the overall query into a view (eg. view1)
I then created another view(eg. view2) to compare the 3 values to produce the value in the “Overall Value”
My logic worked and I am getting the expected output, but I would like to do this all in a single view instead of creating one view to feed into another.  How can I do this?

You omitted any actual sample data from your question, but assuming there is some id column which defines every group of scores, we can try an aggregation approach:
SELECT id, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE score IN ('good', 'passing score')) > 0
                THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS overall_score
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;


Thanks, Tim! I’m pretty new to posting here, so I couldn’t quite articulate my question clearer with some sample date and my expected output.  I posted a new question with the expected output and sample query that should hopefully help - thanks!
